# Implement a different Action Bar item in each fragment of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have a Navigation drawer with fragments. In all the fragments it shows a button item in `main.xml`.

Now, In some fragments I want to implement searchview. For that I made `search.xml` in menu folder.

**search.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_hint"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

What things do I need to implement to achieve this ?

Thanks in Advance

UPDATE: MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "BOOKOS.TTF"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(s);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();


    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], 1));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1],1));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], 1));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], 1));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], 1));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], 1));

    // Recycle the typed array
    //        navMenuIcons.recycle();

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ){
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            SpannableString s = new SpannableString(mTitle);
            s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(getApplicationContext(), "BOOKOS.TTF"), 0, s.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setTitle(s);
         //   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons

            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            SpannableString s = new SpannableString(mDrawerTitle);
            s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(getApplicationContext(), "BOOKOS.TTF"), 0, s.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setTitle(s);
         //   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
      //  displayView(0);
    }
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    displayView(7);

}
/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new IntroductionFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new PrefaceFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PreambleFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new ContentsFragment();
        break;

    case 4:
        fragment = new SchedulesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new AppendixFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new AmendmentFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new PhotoFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
ActionProvider mActionProvider;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 // Find the share item
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    // Need to use MenuItemCompat to retrieve the Action Provider
    mActionProvider = (ActionProvider)
        MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_share:
        Intent ints=new Intent(this,ShareActivity.class);

        startActivity(ints);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_share).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(mTitle);
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "BOOKOS.TTF"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(s);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
}
```

My Fragment class

```
public class IntroductionFragment extends Fragment{

public IntroductionFragment(){
    setRetainInstance(true); 
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);   
}
 Button b;

 TextView tv1;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_introduction,container,false);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Introduction");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(getActivity(), "BOOKOS.TTF"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "BOOKOS.TTF");

     tv1 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setTypeface(typeface);

    getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    return rootView;
} 




@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.v("inside onCreateOptionsMenu","???????");
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

}







@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_introduction, null);
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) getView();
    rootView.removeAllViews();
    rootView.addView(view);

}
}
```

This is the logging

```
07-27 17:27:16.200: V/inside onCreateOptionsMenu(19875): ???????
07-27 17:27:16.210: W/dalvikvm(19875): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d98450)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.MainActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:244)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2494)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(FragmentActivity.java:491)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivity.java:240)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:160)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivity.java:212)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:480)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnPreparePanel(ActionBarActivity.java:236)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onPreparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:155)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onPreparePanel(ActionBarActivity.java:204)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:290)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:425)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:751)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2595)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:648)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:170)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at com.vivekwarde.indianconstitution.IntroductionFragment.onCreateView(IntroductionFragment.java:48)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
07-27 17:27:16.280: E/AndroidRuntime(19875):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For every fragment that needs to have a menu:

- In the constructor call `this.setHasOptionsMenu(true)`.
- Implement `onCreateOptionsMenu(..)` and `onOptionsItemSelected(..)` to handle the menu items for that fragment.

In the drawer layout:

- Whenever you switch fragments, call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on your activity.

If you're using support-v4 fragments, call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`. There are some differences between Android versions in how they handle this stuff, so make sure you test on Ice Cream Sandwich, Jelly Bean and KitKat separately.

Comment: Thank you, I modified my fragment class as you said but I am getting nullpointer exception in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` after implementing ur ans. Also I have confusion where to call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`. See my edit, I hope you can figure out my mistake

Comment: It's probably this bit: `getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);`, you should replace that by `inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);`.

Comment: If you don't post the exception stack trace, there's little point in trying to debug it.

Comment: Okay, now follow the topmost stack frame to line 244 of MainActivity. Look at that line of code and see which of the references on that line of code may be causing the null pointer exception. Add a null check if needed or change the code in some other way to avoid dereferencing the null reference.

Comment: Thanks giving a if condition for fragment & inflating the menu in  onPrepareOptionsMenu  solved

Comment: The error is solved I do not see the item of `main.xml` in IntroductionFragment & also I do not see the searchview of `search.xml` ? Can you tell what could be the problem?

Comment: due to `menu.clear() ` does not let me see the item of main.xml, upto here it is correct but I am unable to see Searchview in this fragment

Comment: yes at that time(without `menu.clear()`) I saw the share  item of main.xml

Comment: I have started the bounty on this question stackoverflow.com/questions/21431856/change-action-bar-item-to-searchview-in-a-fragment-of-navigation-drawer